# BATCH - How to make ">" flash repeatedly next to the input area?

Tags: batch-file

What I want is an this ">" to flash repeatedly next to the input place (i don't know what its called).
Is it possible to do that in batch? It's not mandatory, but i think that it will make my test game look better. 
Each frame:

>

>

>

Just simply flashing repeatedly with like a 1 second interval between each flash, and the ">" stays on screen for like half a second.

Comment: Echo the '>', use ping to wait, clear screen, repeat?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything as I don't know how to code the "input area" not what appears on the screen. I will try what you said, thanks.

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't- at least not without using 'cls' which would clear unnecessarily all previous program output. (Unless this input is the very first thing in your program).

Answer (score 0):

this will make a blinking prompt and preserve previous output.

```
@echo off
set /p a=%cd% <nul
:a
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2 >nul 2>&1
set /p b=^H^><nul
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2 >nul 2>&1
set /p b=^H <nul
goto a
```

use an editor such as vim to make the control-H's (^H)

Comment: Nice try... where can you input something?

Comment: @echo off
set /p a=%cd% <nul
:a
cls
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2 >nul 2>&1
set /p b=^>^><nul
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 2 >nul 2>&1
set /p b=^> <nul
goto a
pause

Comment: you could use choice with a timer... comment and I will fix it in a bit if you say to, though it might get long...